VS2022 "Attach to Process" has wrong machine name for my laptop
This is bonkers.
In my C# solution, I have a WPF WinForms project set as the Startup project, and two Services set to "Always start when debugging".
Yesterday, I was working away in Visual Studio 2022 (v17.10.5), running my C# app in Debug mode, and using the "Attach to Process" window to connect to the Services (both running locally), so I could set breakpoints in them.  Everything was fine.
Then randomly, the "Attach to Process" stopped working.  It seemed to have the wrong computer name, and thinks I'm connecting to a remote server...  I'm not !
The error message says "Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named 'XXXXXX'.  The debugger cannot connect to the remote computer.  The debugger was unable to resolve the specified computer name."
Is there somewhere where I can tell VS2022 the actual name of my computer, so it realises it's localhost ?
Just to add, even if I don't even run my app...  even if I just go into VS2022, and open the "Attach to Process" window, that error occurs.  I've just seen that, in my environment settings, it has my correct computer name (under "COMPUTERNAME") but this "Attach to process" uses a different name... I can't work out why, or where to change it.

I have tested it and did not encounter the same problem as yours. I would like to ask if the "Connection Type" in the "Attach to Process" window is "Local"? If not, please try to switch to the "Local" type.

Hi Cody, yes, it's set to "local".  I believe our company's IT department "updated" our laptop names this week, and this has caused the problem.  If I write C# code to display the value of "System.Environment.MachineName", it displays the new computer name.  But VS2022's "Attach to Process" still thinks my laptop has the old name, and I can't work out how to change this.  I even searched for the old computer name throughout the registry... but found nothing relevant.

Same problem. I've swapped to a new laptop and the debugger is trying to connect to my old one. Something must be stored for computer name but i cannot find it anywhere!

Not a solution but found a way around it, basically i'm using Remote (Windows) and connecting to my local machine!

Same problem. I copied a VS project directory to another machine and when I want to attach to a process of connection type Local it wants to connect to the VS Remote Debugger of the first machine. Cleaning the Solution or Project does not help...

I had the same issue when I copied over my Projects folder from one PC to another. Visual Studio would show the same error, stating the PC name from the first PC, when attempting to attach to the process.
I was able to fix this by closing Visual Studio and then deleting all the .vs folders within the solution directory. These are hidden folders.

The alternative (reluctant) solution is to create a new folder, Clone your code into there, and then it seems to work.
What's annoying is that I can't find the machine name, shown in the message which VS2022 displays ("Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named 'xxxx'."), anywhere in the .vs folders.
I can't see where VS2022 is getting this old machine name from.

Things did not works:

Repair VS
Uninstall and reinstall VS
Uninstall and reinstall IIS
Delete .vs in specific repository
IIS reset.
Machine restart.
And whole lot other things

Finally on desperate attempt to make it work, I have removed all of ".vs" folders exists on my machine and now I can attach to debug.
